# ckeditor，how can I set the background-image of an Element(not the editor itself)?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, background-image

I tried

```
CKEDITOR.dom.setStyle('background-image','url(someUrl)');
```

in the beginning, but when I use

```
CKEDITOR.instance.getData()
```

the quote in the url was excaped to `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

I use regExp to replace the quote now.Any awsome method?